# using perl's PDF::API2::SIMPLE -- Header and Footer

Tags: perl, perl-module

How do I get the header and footer not to print on the first page?

Comment: If PDF::API2::Simple doesn't give you the level of control you need, you can always fall back to PDF::API2.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a crude but working example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::API2::Simple;

our $PageNo;

my $pdf = PDF::API2::Simple->new(
    file   => 'file.pdf',
    header => \&header,
    footer => \&footer,
);

$pdf->add_font('Verdana');

for my $page (1..3) {
    $pdf->add_page;
    $pdf->text( 'blah' x 300, autoflow => 'on' );
}
$pdf->save;  


sub header { 
    $PageNo++;
    return if $PageNo == 1;
    shift->text( 'Header text here' );
}

sub footer { 
    return if $PageNo == 1;
    shift->text( 'page:  ' . $PageNo, x => 10, y => 10 );
}
```